# Add new records to multiple non related tables in Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have 2 nonrelated tables in my application. Student table and log table. ANd there is no relation with these 2 tables. How can i insert record to both these tables in a single go. Like if i create a new student i want to insert to student table and then to Log table (Log table is just an app log that explains the various activities of a user, just for tracking)
The code i used is

```
dbAccountContext.AddTouserdetails(detail);//Adds to Student Table
        string desc=string.Format("new account {0} with username {1} added ", detail.useraccount.Name , detail.useraccount.UserName );
        log logitem = new log { Description = desc, Module = "account", Action = "add user", useraccount = author, Time = DateTime.Now, Level = "1" };
        dbAccountContext.AddTologs(logitem);
        dbAccountContext.SaveChanges();
```

BUt on line .AddToLogs i am getting the exception **" entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"**
How can i avoid this ? How to add records to 2 tables

Comment: Where does `author` come from?

Comment: author is an istance of logged in user , which is retrieved from session like
  actionmodels.useraccount author = (actionmodels.useraccount)Session["CurrentUser"];

Comment: Looks like that's the object that gets tracked multiple times. You should probably detach it first and attach it to `dbAccountContext`.

Comment: Yes exactly thats the issue..Thanks for helping to figure it out